# Internationalisation (i18n) for number, date & currency (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, internationalization

I need to use Internationalisation for my Spring Project. I've seen examples of [jQuery Globalize](https://blog.jquery.com/2015/04/23/announcing-globalize-1-0/), but still can not understand it. I have seen also the sample in the `examples` folder of `jQuery Globalize`. I expected that if I change the language of my browser and OSX (to Italian), I should get the date in Italian and currency in euro, but it was still in english and dollar.
My question is that how can I have the functionality of changing date and currency format in my browsers using `JavaScript` Internationalisation?

Sorry if my question seem banal, but I am new to internationalisation issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's explained pretty well on their website. 
Changing your Browser language will have no effect. You need to format your javascript strings with jQuery Globalize.

Example (from the website):

```
Globalize("en").formatDate(new Date());
// > "11/27/2015"
```